# Prove that there is no odd $n$ such that $\phi (n) = 2^{32}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I've encountered this problem, which I believe is very simple, but I didn't manage to solve it myself.

**Prove that there is no odd $n$ such that $\phi (n) = 2^{32}$, where $\phi$ is Euler's function.**

I managed to show that if $\phi(n) = 2^r$ for some $r$, then $n$ is the product of distinct primes, but now I'm stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: No, $n$ is not always a product of distinct primes.  It could be (a) a power of 2, (b) a product of distinct odd primes, or (c) a product of (a) and (b).  Eg $60 = 2^2×3×5$ and its totient is $16=2^4$.

Comment: An easy proof that the $5$th Fermat number $ F(5)=1+2^{32}$ is not prime: The prime number $641$ is equal to $5\cdot 2^7+1$ and is equal to $5^4 +2^4. $ Now modulo $641$ we have $5^4F(5)\equiv$ $5^4+5^4\cdot2^{32}\equiv$ $5^4+2^4(5\cdot 2^7)^4\equiv $ $5^4+2^4(-1)^4\equiv$ $ 5^4+2^4\equiv 0.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course there are such $n$. The simplest is $n=2^{33}$.  And there are several others. The next simplest is $3\cdot 2^{32}$.

Maybe you want to show that there is no **odd** natural number $n$ such that $\varphi(n)=2^{32}$. **Edit:** The question was changed, with "odd" inserted.

Any such odd $n$ would have to be the product of distinct Fermat  primes, that is, primes of the form $2^{2^k}+1$.

Note that by a result of Euler, $2^{2^5}+1$ is not prime. The only smaller Fermat primes are $2^{2^k}+1$ for $k=0$ to $4$. But the product $(2^{2^0}+1)(2^{2^1}+1)(2^{2^2}+1)(2^{2^3}+1)(2^{2^4}+1)$ is less than $2^{32}$ (by one unit).

Comment: You are right, sorry, fixed it.