# For every odd $n \in \mathbb{N}$ prove that $\phi(n)$ is not equal $2^{32}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have a question:

I proved that If $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is an odd number and $\phi(n)$ is a power of $2$ then $n$ is a product of distinct primes.

Now I need to prove that for every odd $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then  $\phi(n) \neq 2^{32}$.

Can someone give me an advice?

Comment: If an odd prime $p$ satisfies $\phi(p)$ is a power of $2,$ then $p$ is a [Fermat prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number). Then this should show that $\phi(n)\not=2^{32},$ as Fermat primes are not many.

Comment: Euler showed that $2^{32}+1$ is not prime.

Comment: See also: [Prove that there is no odd $n$ such that $\phi (n) = 2^{32}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1537484)

Answer (score 1):

Assume there is a number $n=p_1\times p_2\times ...\times p_k$ that $\phi(n) = 2^{32}$.

It is obvious that $\phi(n) = (p_1-1)\times(p_2-1)\times...\times(p_k-1)$, thus all $p_i$ must be one plus a power of 2.
If $p_i > 2^{32} + 1$, then $\phi(n) > 2^{32}$. Thus the values of $p_i$ can be only chosen in a finite set. Thus there is finitely many values of n to try.